# Run Spice Simulation via Python Script On Windows

Tags: python, pspice

I use python to generate some spice files. I want to simulate them and get the output form the python script as well. Is there a good way of doing that?

SPICE3f5 -  can't seem to find windows executable
Pspice - psp_cmd.exe does not seem to work, at least for the free version that i got.
ngspice - how could i trigger simulation directly from python?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your SPICE version - does it matter?

If not, you should be able to run SPICE simulations controlled from python scripts with [eispice](http://www.thedigitalmachine.net/eispice.html)

Another altnative is, interfacing SPICE OPUS with [PyOPUS](http://www.youspice.com/ys/gettingstartedwithpyopus.3sp)